# Use HTTPClient or HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, rest, httpclient, httpurlconnection

We're implementing a REST client on JRE 1.4.

Seems two good options for a client REST framework are [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) and [HttpUrlConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Is there a reason to use HttpClient over the JRE's HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: That comparison is actually looking at innovations HTTPClient, it has nothing to do with Apache's HttpClient afaik

Comment: Thanks objects.. removed link.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you a single, concrete reason to favour Apache's HTTPClient over the JDK implementation: The JDK's `HttpUrlConnection` doesn't support timeouts*, Apache's HTTPClient does.

Applications should always have the ability to set timeouts when calling into other systems (databases, remote services, your own server backend, ...).

*** This was fixed in Java 1.5; Java 1.5 and higher support timeouts in HttpUrlConnection.**

Comment: Not true!  This was fixed in Java 1.5.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Good to know (it's on the URLConnection class).

Comment: Good point.  We're on 1.4 so this appears totally relevant.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend Jakarta Commons HTTP Client over java.net.HttpUrlConnection as it is more mature and has a [richer feature set](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html).  For example you can ask it to set up multi-threaded connection pool (see [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html)), and it has full support for all the HTTP methods (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE).

Answer (score 2):

The [Restlet Framework](http://www.restlet.org) also has an API which works both server-side and client-side. We support pluggable client connectors, leveraging HttpURLConnection or Apache HTTP Client or our own internal HTTP client.

Our ClientResource class provides a higher level HTTP client API, with features like automatic redirection, transparent conversion between objects and representations, content negotiation and more.

Best regards,

Jerome Louvel

Restlet ~ Founder and Lead developer ~ http://www.restlet.org

Noelios Technologies ~ Co-founder ~ http://www.noelios.com

Comment: We're on 1.4 - does Restlet work on 1.4?

Comment: @Marcus: Yes, it does, I'm using Restlet's client right now in Java 1.6 and it's a dream.  (We have it configured to sit on top of Apache HTTP Client, which is much better than java.net.HttpUrlConnection.)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience HttpClient is slightly easier and more intuitive to use than using HttpUrlConnection, but I think it's a very subjective decision and YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the JRE version just so I would have one less dependency to ship around.

Comment: This comparison looks kinda dated

Comment: Some of us don't have the luxury of using the latest versions of **anything** :-(

Answer (score 1):

... httpclient does not support kerberos/ntlm authentication for proxies etc...
java's httpurlconnection will do authentication out of the box...

Answer (score 0):

The HttpUrlConnection is easy to handle. REST implementations are quite simple.

Although you must consider the whole environment about this implementation and check what will work better for you.