# updating from HttpClient to HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, forms, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I've been working on an android app, and recently got all of the login code working using `HttpClient`. However, this code is now deprecated and no longer works. The language summary suggests replacing all `HttpClient` code with `HttpURLConnection` objects. I'm not sure how to do that though. If anyone could help me change my code to `HttpURLConnection` to submit a login form and retrieve information, it would be greatly appreciated. here is my original use-to-function code:

```
String u = params[0];
String p = params[1];
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS,Boolean.TRUE);
//client.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://home-access.cfisd.net/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn");
List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LogOnDetails.Username", u));
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LogOnDetails.Password",p));
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Database","10"));
HttpResponse response = null;
try{
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
    response = client.execute(post);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Comment: You can refer to this post to convert your code using HttpUrlConnection. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: I tried looking into all of these ideas, and they're all just not quite getting me there. they all terminate with a response code 200, but none will ever continue to the next page after logging in. Is there something more I need to do or that I am missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739548/use-httpclient-or-httpurlconnection?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534342/how-to-switch-from-httpurlconnection-to-httpclient?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534342/how-to-switch-from-httpurlconnection-to-httpclient?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey bro get a library like

androids defaults are old and clunky

[loopjs asynchttpclient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) or [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) or [Koushs ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)

You do a whole lot of work with 2-3 lines of code

**loopjs async http example**

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("key", "value");
params.put("more", "data");
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(url, params, responseHandler);

//do something with response
@Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get output stream for the connection and write the parameter query string to it.

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setReadTimeout(10000);

conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

conn.setDoInput(true);

conn.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

writer.write(getQuery(params));

writer.flush();

writer.close();

os.close();

conn.connect();
```

....

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;

for (NameValuePair pair : params)
{
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        result.append("&");

    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
    result.append("=");
    result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
}

return result.toString();
}
```